# Cannot update simple product of configurable product, Error in update query of Catalog Inventory Stock status table in Magento 2.4 CE

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4, out-of-stock

I created configurable product with variants. Even though I added

- quantity per source for each sub product > 0
- manage stock as "Yes"
- Stock Status as In Stock

It shows Out of Stock.
Also tried clearing cache, reindexing, etc. But nothing solves the issue. What needs to be done to show the product as In Stock?

While updating the sub product (simple product) the following error is shown

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.cataloginventory_stock_status' doesn't exist, query was: UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_status` SET `stock_status` = ?
```

There is a table prefix used but not generated in the above query.
The product update works fine for other kinds of products.
Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Do you know where this query comes from ? Do you have some custom/third party modules ? It is possible that the query is built without using the Magento methods, and setting directly the table name. It would work in most cases but when there is a prefix set like your case, it won't.

Comment: There are no other third other than stripe module for payment

Comment: In your code (`app/code` and `vendor/`), search for occurencies of the string "cataloginventory_stock_status" which might be used directly as the table name, instead of using methods like `$this->getTable('cataloginventory_stock_status')` (which will add the prefix of the table).